# Global Menu not working with flatpaks and snaps

Tags: globalmenu, kdenlive

I am baffled by this. So in Both Ubuntu 18.04 Unity and Gnome the global menu is not working with flatpaks and snaps. In Gnome I have this extension installed https://gitlab.com/lestcape/Gnome-Global-AppMenu and I reported this to the developer and he tried to help (a lot) but we could not figure it out and we think it is the system itself since it is not working in Unity either.

Works with all apps from repositories and appimages. Kdenlive, GIMP, Krita, Transmission, none work as flatpaks or snaps. For instance Kdenlive (same version) works as appimage, but not as flatpak. GIMP works when installed from repo but not as snap.

What could I do? Check? reinstall?

The developer of the Gnome-Global-AppMenu tested it and it works just fine with all apps, so it is something to do with my own system.

As a last resort he recommended:

---

```
sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```

Also you need to remove unity-gtk-module before install appmenu-gtk-module:

```
sudo apt purge unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module sudo apt autoremove
```

---

Needless to say it did not work.

Maybe any of you here and help me out. Global Menu and HUD are so useful I just can't do without them. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to find a solution. Also I have the same problem with Gimp and Audacity both flatpak without Global Menu